# Tabbing between data cells horizontaly & vertically

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel worksheet that is used to issue a badge to employees.

All the *non data cells* have been locked, which prevents entries in these areas.

When I tab, excel does go to the next data cell in that row. However it does not tab to the next lower row where other data cells are located. Data cells are located at:

`C11; B21, H21; B24, E24, G24, H24, J24; B27, E27, G27; C28; G30, I30; B34`. The OS I use is MS 2010.

I have googled, & have not found a solution to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What version of Excel and what OS are you using? I am using 2010 and am unable to duplicate what you are seeing. Mine tabs to the next unlocked cell on the same row, then down to the next row with an unlocked cell, then across that row, etc.

Comment: If the whole sheet is protected and all cells are locked except for the data entry cells and the protection is set so only can select unlocked cells it should work.

Comment: The sheet is protected & the user is only able to use unlocked cells.

Comment: I protected the sheet & it still only goes horizontally.

Comment: It should loop through the all unlocked cells on a sheet using tab and return to where you started.  Does it do that?    Perhaps double check you're not looking at unticked "Hidden" instead of unticked "Locked".  I can't imagine what it wouldn't be working.